# TLV Macro expansion raises warning: Assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast

Tags: c, tlv

My TLV structure can hold string or integer.  I'm trying to create a macro that handles them both.

The example below runs as expected, but it compiles with warnings from the MACRO expansion. I understand the precompiler cannot know what type of value I'm going to assign at runtime, which is why I think it's raising the warning.

How can this little code snippet be fixed so it generates no compile warnings?

FWIW, I can code around this by not using the MACRO, but would prefer to use it if possible.

```
$ gcc -o simple{,.c} && ./simple
simple.c: In function ‘main’:
simple.c:25:21: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
       tlv.value_str = (val); \
                     ^
simple.c:38:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘TLV2STR_MACRO’
   TLV2STR_MACRO(string, TYPE_INT, 11);
   ^
simple.c:28:21: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
       tlv.value_int = (val); \
                     ^
simple.c:41:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘TLV2STR_MACRO’
   TLV2STR_MACRO(string, TYPE_STRING, "ELEVEN");
   ^
-----------------------------
INT   : 11
STRING: ELEVEN
-----------------------------
```

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct _tlv_s {
  int type;
  size_t length;
  union _value {
    int value_int;
    char *value_str;
  } value_u;
} tlv_t;

#define value_int value_u.value_int
#define value_str value_u.value_str

#define TYPE_STRING 0
#define TYPE_INT 1

#define TLV2STR_MACRO(s, t, val) { \
    tlv_t tlv; \
    tlv.type = (t); \
    if (t == TYPE_STRING) { \
      tlv.value_str = (val); \
      sprintf(s, "STRING: %s", tlv.value_str); \
    } else { \
      tlv.value_int = (val); \
      sprintf(s, "INT   : %d", tlv.value_int); \
    } \
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char string[128];

  printf("-----------------------------\n");
  TLV2STR_MACRO(string, TYPE_INT, 11);
  printf("%s\n", string);

  TLV2STR_MACRO(string, TYPE_STRING, "ELEVEN");
  printf("%s\n", string);
  printf("-----------------------------\n");

}
```

Comment: Any reason why you can't add a cast to the relevant lines: `tlv.value_str = (char*)(val);` and `tlv.value_int = (int)(val);` ?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I tried that and it fixed one of the cases and the other case has a slightly different warning.  I now get:

simple.c:25:23: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
       tlv.value_int = (int)(val); \
                       ^
simple.c:38:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘TLV2STR_MACRO’
   TLV2STR_MACRO(string, TYPE_STRING, "ELEVEN");
   ^

Comment: With the clarity of a new morning, I don't think it will be possible to achieve what I first hoped for.  Instead, if I modify the macro to pass around pointers to values, then I can cast those pointers.  It then corrects the warnings.  I'll post my solution.

Answer (score 0):

> How can this little code snippet be fixed so it generates no compile warnings?

You can add explicit casts.

```
tlv.value_str = (char*)(val); \
tlv.value_int = (int)(val); \
```

To your FWIW, such macro will not scale up, while it is fast to write for a toy example with two types and one use case, it will become painful and unreadable when more to come. Use [virtual table](https://lwn.net/Articles/444910/) with dispatch functions, keep your code readable, prefer not to use macros. I suggest removing confusing definitions `#define value_int value_u.value_int` and keeping your symbols within one namespace `tlv_*`. Do not end up with [unreadable big switches](https://github.com/Gurux/GuruxDLMS.c/blob/d268abd7379ef17f1bb98a8d0b24c9cbba8be0b6/development/src/variant.c#L859), which your code seems to be going for. Prefer to use `snprintf` instead of `sprintf`.

Comment: All good tips, thank you.  I tried your suggestion and the warning morphed to be: simple.c:25:23: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast] tlv.value_int = (int)(val); \ ^ simple.c:38:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘TLV2STR_MACRO’.

Comment: `tlv.value_int = (int)(uintptr_t)(val);`

Comment: Right, that's the idea.  It means I must pass the values as pointers, and not as literal strings or integer values.  I'll post my solution and glad for your commentary.

Answer (score 0):

I believe (glad to be proven otherwise) that it is not possible to pass values around as I had intended, casting them arbitrarily to string or integer.

Instead, passing *pointers* to values and casting the *pointers* is the proper way to do this.  (As an aside, if this was truly a TLV implementation, it would handle any kind of structure, but this is just a dinky little app to demo the issue with passing values).

Notice that I modified the macro to accept a *pointer* to the value.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct _tlv_s {
  int type;
  size_t length;
  union _value {
    int value_int;
    char *value_str;
  } value_u;
} tlv_t;

#define value_int value_u.value_int
#define value_str value_u.value_str

#define TYPE_STRING 0
#define TYPE_INT 1

#define TLV2STR_MACRO(s, t, valp) { \
    tlv_t tlv; \
    tlv.type = (t); \
    if (t == TYPE_STRING) { \
      tlv.value_str = (char *)(valp); \
      sprintf(s, "STRING: %s", tlv.value_str); \
    } else { \
      tlv.value_int = *(int *)(valp); \
      sprintf(s, "INT   : %d", tlv.value_int); \
    } \
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char string[128];
  int val_int = 11;

  printf("-----------------------------\n");
  TLV2STR_MACRO(string, TYPE_INT, &val_int);
  printf("%s\n", string);

  TLV2STR_MACRO(string, TYPE_STRING, "ELEVEN");
  printf("%s\n", string);
  printf("-----------------------------\n");

}
```

And the output from compile and run....

```
$ gcc -o simple{,.c} && ./simple asdf 
-----------------------------
INT   : 11
STRING: ELEVEN
-----------------------------
```